# get the data from set of array inside array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I stuck in angularjs to get data as below i got the data from API as below:

```
{
data: [
{
nightsInDest: null,
airlines: [
"A3",
"D8",
"DY"
],
route: [
{
cityTo: "Athens",
flyFrom: "IKA",
},
{
cityTo: "Copenhagen",
flyFrom: "ATH",
},
{
cityTo: "London",
flyFrom: "CPH",
},
{
cityTo: "Los Angeles",
flyFrom: "LGW",

}
],
}
```

as you see data is array and length is something like 136 and inside there is ailines that length is 3 that array and I have 1 route that length is 4 I make a for loop for data :

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.results; i++)
```

and get data but when I arrive to route I don't know how to get the data of

```
cityTo: "Copenhagen"
```

in my html view:

```
<h4 class="box-title">From {{data[$index].route[$index].cityFrom}} to {{data[$index].route[$index].cityTo}} </h4>
```

for first data0 cityTo0 and show me Athen but for next data0 cityTo1 I dont know how to get it and go to data1 cityTo1

I know its complecate and I dont know how to explain more and data is so huge and I had to delete some part for easeier to read and if some one can help me its realy save my day and appritiate

ps:
I make 1 for loop for route (but Im sure its wrong)

```
 $scope.numberOfFlights = $scope.data[i].route.length;

for (var j = 0; j < $scope.numberOfFlights; j++) {
```

[image]

Comment: What data do you need? Can you provide an example of what exactly you're trying to display? I'm happy to help, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: these data are for ailines and routes are stopover of each airline `airlines: [
"A3",
"D8",
"DY"
],` I need for pass to ng-source to get the flight logo
and `route: [
{
cityTo: "Athens",` 
I need to get for destination and show in view and ng-repeat for all data 
I hope I made it clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'd set your data into a variable called 'flights' then ng-repeat over it and the routes in them. Something like:

Javascript:

```
$scope.flights = results.data;
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="flight in flights">
    <h4 ng-repeat="connection in flight.route">
        From {{connection.cityFrom}} to {{connection.cityTo}}
    </h4>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how you're getting the logos.

Comment: Thanks alot with some small changes its solved my problem @Jeremy

Comment: Happy to help! :)